# how to retrieve parse object to recycle view with fragment

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I try to retrieve parse object on `recyclerview`. but data not showing. in logcat

```
12-08 22:14:41.222 23950-23950/com.keboo.ime E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
12-08 22:14:41.313 23950-23950/com.keboo.ime E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout


public class TerasFragment extends Fragment {

public TerasAdapter terasAdapter;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;

public TerasFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("teras");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                terasAdapter = new TerasAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_teras, container, false);

    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_status);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(terasAdapter);
    return view;
}
}


  public class TerasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TerasAdapter.ViewHolder>{

List<ParseObject> mlist;
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public TerasAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> list){
    this.mlist = list;
    this.mContext = context;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = inflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.teras_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ParseObject status = mlist.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(status.getString("nama"));
    holder.status.setText(status.getString("status"));
    ParseFile picture = (ParseFile) status.get("picture");
    picture.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(byte[] bytes, ParseException e) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            holder.profil.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    CardView mCardView;
    CircleImageView profil;
    TextView name, type, time, status;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mCardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv_status);
        profil = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.de_status_profil);
        name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status_nama);
        type = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status_type);
        time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvstatus_time);
        status = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_status_deskription);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Added answer please check

Comment: thaks for respons
@VividVervet i'm sorry, i dont understand ur answer code, where i put setListView method? 
sorry my english not good.

Comment: First change your  getItemCount method and check

Comment: getItemCount should return mList.size() not zero.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you're doing the parsing in a thread other than UI thread, so it works asynchronous to UI thread, so you have to set the adapter after processing the parsing or you have to notify the adapter. you are getting the message Skipping layout, because there is no data to be displayed in your Recyclerview. so what you have to do is

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("teras");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                setListView(list);
            }
        }
    });
}



public void setListView(List<ParseObject< list){
  terasAdapter = new TerasAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), list);
  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_status);
  recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext));
  recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
  recyclerView.setAdapter(terasAdapter);
}
```

and there is an error in your adapter's *getItemCount()* method, instead of returning 0 you have to return the size of your list.

ex:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```